# Maintaining text quality in QHD+ mode or high DPI situation

Tags: c#, winforms, highdpi

How do I maintain text quality in high DPI mode? I want to take layout and text into account - specifically, my text is blurry.

I tried `SetProcessDPIAware()`, but this method just ignored DPI.

Comment: Can you post some of the code you're currently using?

Comment: Please provide more details.

Comment: i think don't need code because it is just create winform and add label. and i excute on high dpi windows.